# Jetty ResourceCache vs CachedContentFactory

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

I am migrating from Jetty `9.0.x` to `9.4.x`

`org.eclipse.jetty.server.ResourceCache` is removed from Jetty `9.4.x`

Questions:

1) What is the replacement for this class in `9.4.x` ?

2) I found `CachedContentFactory` is the closest equivalent of this class but constructor of this class takes one extra parameter `CompressedContentFormat[] precompressedFormats`. if this is a correct replacement then I am not sure what should I pass it in for this param? can it be empty array ? Sorry, javadocs did not help a lot either.

Comment: Before I answer, why were you customizing the `ResourceCache` (a purely internal class)?  Chances are the things you were doing are done elsewhere now.

Comment: I am overriding `isCacheable(Resource resource)` method which reads a boolean value which tells whether resource caching is enabled or not for all resources.` @Override
 protected boolean isCacheable(Resource resource) {
  if (!cacheEnabled) return false;
  return super.isCacheable(resource);
 } ` Mostly it's true in all cases and we may not even need to override it. Regardless, would like to know the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First some history.

Back during the major release Jetty 9.0.0 there were 2 main ways to handle static content:
`DefaultHandler` (and the inferior `ResourceHandler`).

When major release Jetty 9.4.0 rolled out (this is 4 major version releases of Jetty later then Jetty 9.0.0) an effort was made to make both of those component use a common codebase, so the `ResourceService` was created to standardize the servicing of static content in a single place.   Now the differences between `DefaultHandler` and `ResourceHandler` were vastly reduced.  (*note: `DefaultHandler` still supports more features of its own and more features of the various HTTP specs*)

Next, [Issue #539](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/issues/539) was resolved to allow the `ResourceHandler` (and now `DefaultHandler`) to have customized directory listings.  To accomplish this the `HttpOutput.ContentFactory` interface was introduced.

The new `HttpOutput.ContentFactory` was responsible for returning the `HttpContent` representing the path provided (and an optional maximum buffer size configuration option).

So that means, at this point we have ...

1. A `DefaultServlet` (or `ResourceHandler`)
2. Which has a `ResourceService`
3. Which gets it's content from a `HttpOutput.ContentFactory`
4. The returned `HttpContent` can be a static resource, a directory listing, or a welcome file.

When it comes time to send a piece of static content the steps taken are ...

1. Ask for `HttpContent` object from `HttpOutput.ContentFactory.getContent(path, maxBufferSize)`
2. Ask for representation of `HttpContent` that can be used to send the referenced  content, one of the following (in this order):

   1. If `HttpChannel` is configured to use "direct buffers", then ask for `HttpContent.getDirectBuffer()` representing the entire content. (this could be a memory mapped file using a negligible amount of heap memory)
   2. Ask for `HttpContent.getIndirectBuffer()` representing the entire content. (this could be a memory mapped file using a negligible amount of heap memory)
   3. Ask for `HttpContent.getReadableByteChannel()` to send content.
   4. Ask for `HttpContent.getInputStream()` to send content.
3. Return error indicating "Unknown Content"

There are 2 major implementations of `HttpOutput.ContentFactory` present in Jetty 9.4.0+

- `ResourceContentFactory` which handles transient content (not cached) - if content exceeds `maxBufferSize` then raw `ByteBuffer` versions will not be returned.
- `CachedContentFactory` which will cache various `ByteBuffer` values returned from previous `HttpOutput` usage.

The `CachedContentFactory` has a `isCacheable(Resource)` method that is interrogated to know if the supplied resource should enter the in-memory cache or not.

With regards to the `CompressedContentFormat[] precompressedFormats` parameter in the `CachedContentFactory` constructor, that refers to the "pre-compressed" formats supported by both the `ResourceService` and the `CachedContentFactory`.

Typical, default, setup is ...

```java
CompressedContentFormat[] precompressedFormats = {
    CompressedContentFormat.GZIP, // gzip compressed
    CompressedContentFormat.BR, // brotli compressed
    new CompressedContentFormat("bzip", ".bz") // bzip compressed
};
CachedContentFactory cachedContentFactory = new CachedContentFactory(parentContentFactory,
   resourceFactory, mimeTypes, useFileMappedBuffers,
   useEtags, precompressedFormats);
resourceService.setContentFactory(cachedContentFactory);
```

These `precompressedFormats` refer to static (and immutable) content that has been precompressed before server startup.

This allows a client to send a request for say ...

```
GET /css/main.css HTTP/1.1
Host: example.hostname.com
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

and if the "Base Resource" directory has a `${resource.basedir}/css/main.css` **AND** a `${resource.basedir}/css/main.css.gz` then the response will be served from the `main.css.gz` (not the `main.css`), resulting in an HTTP response like ...

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 15 May 2019 20:17:22 GMT
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Last-Modified: Wed, 15 May 2019 20:17:22 GMT
Content-Type: text/css
ETag: W/"H/6qTDwA8vsH/6rJoEknqc"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 11222
```

Comment: Also, found that ` HtpOutput.sendContent(HttpContent content) throws IOException` commits the http channel. So any second attempt of calling `sendContent` throws an IO exception. It wasn't a problem before in 9.0. Any inputs ? (fyi this is how I get HttpOutput  --> `ServletOutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream()` and `outputStream instanceof HttpOutput = true` )

Comment: If you reach/enter `ResourceHandler` or `DefaultServlet` that's it, there's nothing else after it, ever.  Doing stuff after those execute are not supported.  What on earth are you doing??  You really shouldn't be mucking about deep in the ResourceService or HttpOutput.ContentFactory.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sagar4848/d218ede7f1f1ecb1449b0f45f8cb4f87 In this gist I am trying to concatenate bunch of resources files and writing them to ServletOutputStream (HttpOutput in this case) . My default servlet is dispatcher servlet which came up with Spring boot 2.0 along with jetty 9.4. It was all working with Jetty 9.0 without dispatcherServlet.

Comment: Merging static resources together is not done in the ResourceHandler or DefaultHandler, that's why [`org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.ConcatServlet`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.x/jetty-servlets/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/servlets/ConcatServlet.java) exists to handle.